# How to get data of a column into a list from the Database View using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've a database view like this:

```
 id    sub_id   name
   1     1      abc
   1     2      def
   2     1      xyz
   2     2      jkl
   2     3      lko
```

that is mapped into the JPA entity like this:

```
@Entity(name = "entity")
@Immutable
class Entity(
    @EmbeddedId
    val id: Id, // (Combination of id and sub_id)

    @Column(name = "name")
    val data: List<String>
)
```

I want to collect different names from the list of name for a particular id into a list in my jpa entity. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not directly possible with Hibernate, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(DatabaseViewEntity.class)
public interface DatabaseViewDto {
    @IdMapping("this")
    IdDto getId();

    @Mapping("name")
    List<String> getData();

    @EntityView(DatabaseViewEntity.class)
    interface IdDto {
        Long getId();
        Long getSubId();
    }
}
```

With an entity type like:

```
@Entity
public class DatabaseViewEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Id
    private Long subId;
    @Id
    private String name;
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DatabaseViewDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DatabaseViewDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
List<DatabaseViewDto> findAll();
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!